# c#: how to create a custom (virtual) folder in windows and populate it with arbitrary files

Tags: c#, windows-shell, shell-namespace-extension

I have many files, which are in many different folders on my HD, I want to be able to display certain subsets of these files in one place (probably a "virtual" folder in Explorer), based on certain criteria. For example, I want only *.zip files to be displayed or files with size < 100kb. What is the best way to do it in Windows?

I don't want to write my own GUI for that. I was thinking about using Windows search results, but it doesn't fit my purposes. What are my best options? It doesn't matter if it has to be programmed in c#, I could use any solution. I heard about namespace extensions, but there's almost no support or documentation for it for c#, only a paid library.

Comment: Why do you think Windows search doesn't fit your need. You can also save searches like that in files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-savedsearchfileformat

Comment: @SimonMourier I read that the search performs a new search each time when you launch it. Since I already know what files must be displayed and their locations, this is undesired, but I will look deeper into it, thanks.